# DKIM Key Error Message: Invalid selector. Selector must be a valid fragment of a domain name

Tags: dkim

I am receiving an error message when trying to create a DKIM Key:

```
Invalid selector. Selector must be a valid fragment of a domain name.




Key Size: 2048-bit
Selector: Salesforce "Instance Name"
Alternate Selector: Salesforce "Instance` Name"2
Domain: domain.co.uk
Domain Match: Exact domain only
```

From all the documentation I have found online, the selector is just a name, so I am not sure why I am receiving this error message. Is there a particular format to use?

I have also tried to include the domain name into the selector, but I am still receiving the same error.

From the documentation I've read online, the "Domain" is the email address 'domain the users have in Salesforce.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: It sounds like the selector name should have a substring/string from the domain itself, though this is not clearly documented. I had recently created a DKIM key in one of the Orgs and had put the Selector (as in your example here) as *domain.co.uk* and Alternate Selector as *domain.co.uk2*, and it had worked successfully.

Comment: @JayantDas - Thanks for your reply and help. I've just managed to create the DKIM Key successfully by using  "domain.co.uk" as a Selector and "domain.co.uk2" as Alternate Selector.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A selector in DKIM must be an alphanumeric string.

If you attempt to use a selector such as *Salesforce "Instance Name"* that contains non-alphanumeric chars, you'll receive the `Invalid selector. Selector must be a valid fragment of a domain name` error message. The first half of the error message is correct, second half is a Salesforce product bug as the issue has nothing to do with domain name.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It makes perfect sense now, even though that information is not clearly explained. Re-watching the video that Salesforce has provided on "How to Setup DKIM Key" makes perfect sense why the Selector and Alternate Selector have been chosen as "test1" and "test1a", so thank you. I managed to created the DKIM successfully now by using the "domain.co.uk" and "domain.co.uk2" as Selectors.